# Spring Security Core Plugin grails 2.4 upgrade from 2.3.7 issue

Tags: grails, spring-security, upgrade

I just upgraded my grails project from 2.3.7 to 2.4 and I've been having issues with the spring security plugin.

My application compiles but when it runs, I get the following error :

```
Error |
2014-06-09 10:26:35,570 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [springSecurityCore:2.0-RC2]: null
Message: null
Line | Method
->>  363 | doStoreMapping            in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    317 | storeMapping              in     ''
|    309 | compileStaticRules . . .  in     ''
|    218 | initialize                in     ''
|    738 | initializeFromAnnotations in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin
|    599 | doCall                    in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure3
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
```

I've also had to fix the one issue in the ReflectionUtils to get it to compile, but I am seem to be hitting a wall here.

I appreciate in advance all the help.

Thanks

Comment: I fixed my issue by changing the version to RC3 instead of RC2 of the spring security core.

Comment: It spot it again in RC4 for me ... RC3 seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to `spring-security-core:RC3`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happens for spring-security-core:RC4 and the only way i found to get rid of it was downgrading to spring-security-core:RC3. After that works like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was due to the database collation.

I was using MySql and setting "default character set utf8 default collate utf8_general_ci" solved it.